# A sequence of random variables converging to uniform r.v.

Tags: probability

Can you give an example of a sequence of random variables $X_n$ with densities $f_n$ converging in distribution to Uniform(0,1) random variable $X$ s.t. $f_n$ does not converge to 1 for any $x \in [0,1]$?

Comment: I would start with $f_n(x) = 2(\pi n x \bmod 1)$ (suitably renormalized to have integral $1$.

Comment: @kimchilover That's interesting. Where did this function come from?

Comment: I don't know.  I thought of densely spaced Dirac combs, as measures converging in distribution to $U[0,1]$, but they don't have densities. I was suspicious of $2\sin^2(\pi n x)$: maybe there would be a few special $x$ values for which you had convergence to $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f_n(x) = \cases{2 & if $\lfloor 2 n x \rfloor$ is odd\cr 0 & otherwise\cr }$$